# Accessing array value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Java Script. I have an some array like this,

```
    var red = [10, 20, 30];
    var blue = [11, 21, 31];
    var green = [12, 22, 32];
    var userSelect = $("#Color").val();
```

Here `userSelect` should be "red", "blue" or "green". I am trying to get the array from user input string. Like, if they input the string "green", I will then show them the array green. What I've tried so far is,

```
     all = [red, blue, green];
     desiredArray = all[userSelect];
```

But it doesn't work. Could someone please point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any one cares to explain the reason of down voting please? It will help me to make a better question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Store the value in object instead of `array` so that you can refer the value using the `key` of the object using [`bracket notation([])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties). This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime).

Try this:

```js
 var red = [10, 20, 30];
 var blue = [11, 21, 31];
 var green = [12, 22, 32];
 var userSelect = $("#Color").val();
 var all = {
   red: red,
   blue: blue,
   green: green
 };
 $('#Color').on('change', function() {
   alert(all[this.value]);
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='Color'>
  <option value='red'>Red</option>
  <option value='green'>Green</option>
  <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Glad it helped! _Happy coding_

Answer (score 2):

This will not work as arrays don't have context about variable name.
Your all will look like `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`. it does not understand red, green or blue.

What you can do is assign these in an Object.

```
var all={
"red": red,
"green":green,
"blue": blue
}

desiredArray = all[userSelect];
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work also: just take the user's string and test it for a match. The downside is that the user could misspell or choose an option that isn't there.

```js
 var red = [10, 20, 30];
 var blue = [11, 21, 31];
 var green = [12, 22, 32];
 var userSelect = prompt("Choose red, green, or blue");
 switch(userSelect) {
  case 'green':
   alert('you chose green: ' + green);
  break;
  case 'red':
   alert('you chose red: ' + red);
  break;
  case 'blue':
   alert('you chose blue: ' + blue);
  break;
  default:
  alert('check your spelling...');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually the place from where I get the user input is a html "select". So the values are predefined.